# In R, is there a way to use regular expressions or something similar to extract the first and last character of an email string?

Tags: r, regex

Currently in R, with data.table, I have the following column:

```
jamesmann@yahoo.com       
bill.free@yahoo.com        
computer.trader@yahoo.com
j*****n@gmail.com
```

which are factors. I would like to parse the above so that I can get the first and last letters of the username before the `@` symbol.

So for the above I'd like to get:

```
jn
be
cr
jn
```

I deal with some asterisked usernames so I added it in too. Is there a simple way to do this? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match the following pattern to the strings and replace it with the capture groups:

```
sub("(.).*(.)@.*", "\\1\\2", s)
## [1] "jn" "be" "cr" "jn"
```

### Note

The input strings in reproducible form is:

```
s <- c("jamesmann@yahoo.com", "bill.free@yahoo.com", "computer.trader@yahoo.com",
  "j*****n@gmail.com")
```